# slideToggle the next element

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I want 5 `<p>` tags that when clicked, display a `<div>` that is underneath. I could do it where I name each `<p>` and each `<div>` different but that would lead to a lot of jQuery.

So, at the moment I have:

```
<p class="flip">Example</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div><!--End panel-->

<p class="flip">Example</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div><!--End panel-->

<p class="flip">Example</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Example Panel</p>
</div><!--End panel-->
```

The jQuery I have at the moment is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flip').click(function() {
    $('.panel').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Which obviously toggles all the `.panels` at once. To clarify, I want the first `.flip` to toggle the first `.panel.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to do some simple DOM traversal to select the correct `<div class="panel">` element relative to the `<p class="flip">` that was clicked on:

```
$('.flip').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('div.panel').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Inside the `click` event handler function, `this` is the `<p>` element that was clicked on. Calling `.next('div.panel')` will select the next element in the DOM if it's a `<div>` and it has the class `panel`. If you need to skip any sibling elements, you can double up the `.next()` calls, like `.next().next()`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot. Not done much work with .next and never seen (e) in the function before, what does it do as it does seem to work without it?

Comment: @user2144363 jQuery passes its normalised `event` object to the event handler function as the first argument. The anonymous function I'm passing to `click` has a single parameter - `e` - which will take the value of that argument. It's only required if you want to work with the event inside the function - such as calling `.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour of that event - but it's a habit for me to always specify it when writing a jQuery event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I have the next problem...I want to when I pulse click over the img `.act` be hidden one in one

I found the solution but for `noact` I would like find the solution for `.act`

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.noact').show();
    $('.act').show();
    $('.noact').click(function(){
        var x = $(this).next('.act') ;
        x.slideToggle(1000);
    });
    $('.act').click(function(){
        $('.noact').slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this answer doesn't add to the quality of the answers to the original question and seems more suited as a new question in its own right. Please consider moving this answer and its concerns into a new question that may be addressed.